# Combine two tables into one table with separated values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a simple rather simple question, but for whatever reason I just can't get to a solution.

How do I join the two tables like such that I have get NULL values like this?

Table #T1

```
A
--
1
2
```

Table #T2

```
B
--
3
```

Desired result:

```
A  B
----
1 NULL
2 NULL
NULL 3
```

EDIT:

My solution was this

```
SELECT #T1.A, #T2.B 
FROM #t2 
RIGHT JOIN #T1 ON 1 = 0

UNION

SELECT #T1.A, #T2.B  
FROM #t2 
LEFT JOIN #t1 ON 1 = 0
```

But it seems overly complicated. Anything better?

Answer (score 3):

Use `FULL JOIN`

```
select * 
   from #t1 t1
   full outer join #t2 t2 on t1.a = t2.b
```

or use `UNION ALL`

```
select a,Null as b 
from #t1
union all 
select NULL, b 
from #t2
```

since there is no common records in both the tables, both the query results will look same. When there is a common record, the result will differ. Use the one that suits your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This is the better/simple one

```
SELECT #T1.A, #T2.B 
FROM #t2 
FULL OUTER JOIN #T1 ON 1 = 0
```

Comment: How it is better and simple? Even syntax is not correct

Comment: Uodated the query. Instead of union all we can use full join.